# How to let user upload a raster in google earth engine

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm working on a Google Earth Engine app where we would like to allow the end user to upload a raster file for use in the calculations. Is there a good way to do this? We already know that a user can manipulate the geometry imports with the drawing tools, but is there a way to just upload a file and then pass the file to an algorithm for processing?

Answer (score 0):

I have a round-about way of doing this. Not sure if there is anything simpler.
The steps include

1. On your earth engine app, include a link to an empty Google Drive (or any other cloud service buckets which has API integration with Google Cloud Platform)
2. Use Google drive API to mount your drive on a local/remote node. Use Google Earth Engine python API to access the inputted raster. Optionally process the input raster
3. Use Google cloud api to upload the raster/processed raster to Google cloud bucket
4. Use Earth Engine api to upload raster/processed raster from Google cloud bucket to Earth Engine Assets
5. Use Earth Engine api to display the new user inputted raster/processed raster in the api.

A working example of the above 5 steps is provided in this [Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1JsL1PP77KPP2C2kvs8WhMhJke4nv8VnM?usp=sharing) and displayed in this [Earth Engine App](https://kkraoj.users.earthengine.app/view/damagemap).